# Longest K unique characters substring (NULL POINTER EXCEPTION ERROR)

Tags: java, string, algorithm, data-structures, nullpointerexception

Please find the error in my code

```
  public int longestkSubstr(String s, int k) {
    // code here
    if(s.length()==0)
    return 0;
    int i=0,j=0;
    int ans=-1;
    Map<Character,Integer> map=new HashMap<>(); 
    while(j<s.length()){
        map.put(s.charAt(j),map.getOrDefault(s.charAt(i),0)+1);
       
        if(map.size()<k)
        j++;
        else if(map.size()==k){
        ans=Math.max(ans,j-i+1);
        j++;
        }
        else if (map.size()>k){
          
        while(map.size()>k){
            
            map.put(s.charAt(i),map.get(s.charAt(i))-1);
            if(map.get(s.charAt(i))==0)
            map.remove(s.charAt(i));
        i++;
     } j++;}   
}
return ans;`}
```

Runtime Error:
Runtime ErrorException in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Solution.longestkSubstr(File.java:43)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: We can only guess here, since you only posted the method where the exception occurs, but now how you call this method. You also didn't provide the information _what line_ line 43 in `longestkSubstr` is. The best thing for you to do is to learn how to use a debugger, to step through your code and find out what exactly is null (and why). Are you sure that `s` is not null?

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Here you've declared **Map** as **<Character, Integer>**. **Integer** type object's value can be **null**.

```
map.put(s.charAt(i),map.get(s.charAt(i))-1);
```

Here in "`map.get(s.charAt(i))-1`", even when `map.get(s.charAt(i))` is returning NULL, your code is still trying to perform arithmatic opearation on that.

This is the reason for showing java.lang.NullPointerException.

> `Map.get()` **returns null when the key is not present**. An Integer
> (autoboxed type) that is null can not be autounboxed into an int, so
> it throws NullPointerException.
>
> Note: [Java uses autoboxing to convert Integer to int](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/autoboxing-unboxing-java/)

***Solution:***

Anywhere you use `map.get`, try to keep a check whether it's null or not.

In your case it might be like following,

```
if( map.get(s.charAt(i)) != null) map.put(s.charAt(i), map.get(ch) - 1);
if (map.get(s.charAt(i)) != null && map.get(s.charAt(i)) == 0)
```

Please check following reference to know more about `get()` method and other uses of Map

- [Map get() method in Java with Examples](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/map-get-method-in-java-with-examples/)
- [Map Interface in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/map-interface-java-examples/)
- [Java Map Interface](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-map)
- [Java HashMap](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-hashmap)

Happy coding!